# How to change color of line under WizardControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Is it possible to set color of the line above Next and Cancel buttons in DevExpress WizardControl ([WizardAero](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4724))? I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: provide more information that what are you trying to do??  check this too - [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Wizard Control has 3 visual parts. Lowest part contains predefined buttons: Back, Next/Finish, Cancel. This third part and second part (from the top) is separated by line. I want to change color of this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this lines(dividers) are painted using skin-images, so there is no direct way to override the colors of these lines.
However, you can override the dividers painting using the following approach:

```
public class MyWizardControl : WizardControl {
    protected override WizardPainter CreatePainter() {
        return new MyWizardPainter();
    }
}
public class MyWizardPainter : WizardPainter {
    protected override WizardClientPainterBase CreateClientPainter(WizardViewInfo viewInfo) {
        return new MyWizardAeroClientPainter(viewInfo);
    }
}
public class MyWizardAeroClientPainter : WizardAeroClientPainter {
    public MyWizardAeroClientPainter(WizardViewInfo viewInfo) : base(viewInfo) { }
    protected override void DrawDividers(GraphicsInfoArgs e) {
        base.DrawDividers(e);
        int bottom = ViewInfo.GetContentBounds().Bottom;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, ClientRect.Left, bottom, ClientRect.Right, bottom);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightPink, ClientRect.Left, bottom + 1, ClientRect.Right, bottom + 1);
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image: Wizard with Pink Divider]